# Can documents be forced in a printing queue?

Tags: windows-7, printer, productivity

I have recently been moved to work on a desk that is a bit far from the printer. One of the tasks I'm supposed to work on requires me to either have documents stacking up in the printer then go get it or make several trips for individual printings. For that reason I could use a button to trigger all the documents to print at once to avoid having my stuff in a pile that might contain someone else's documents.

Is it possible? I'm not allowed to install any software or change most of the properties.

Comment: Tell us more about how you connect to the printer.  If it is connected to a computer, then what OS.  If it is directly connected to the network, then tell us the printer model.  If it is connected through some kind of router/print sharing device then tell us about that.

Comment: @Zoredache The printer is connected to a WIN-7 Desktop via USB, which I access through the network. I can't precise the printer model right now but I can get back at you tomorrow.

Comment: Is it within your power to connect the printer to something else? Or buy an adapter to connect it directly to the network?  I am not sure you will be able to do anything if it is shared from Windows 7, but with an IP-based print-server the queue will live on your workstation.

Comment: @Zoredache No to the first two questions. I can, however, try changing the settings on the computer the desktop is connected to.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the "secure print" option available on some printers. The job will be held on the printer until you enter a PIN number. This [Xerox info sheet](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=xerox%20secure%20print&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CFIQFjAC&url=http://download.support.xerox.com/pub/docs/dnd_secureprint/userdocs/any-os/en_GB/SecurePrint_flyer.pdf&ei=0Xk1UPqKJoz3mAWotYHwBQ&usg=AFQjCNGpKo9qwMmX0vfdO11MRNt933NolQ&cad=rja) gives more details. [HP's Access Control](http://h71028.www7.hp.com/enterprise/us/en/ipg/access-control-secure-print-authentication.html) also gives you PIN controlled printing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and Windows supports this natively:

1. Open up the printer queue for the printer
2. Go to the `Printer` menu and select `Pause Printing`
3. Print documents normally, they'll just pile up in Windows' printer queue
4. Go back to the printer queue and resume printing
5. Collect documents from printer

Comment: That option is grayed out. How can I enable it? It might be because the printer is on the network.

Comment: @Renan Is the `Print Spooler` service running on your system? The option is available on my network printer. It's possible that the option actually pauses printing on the printer and not the print spooler on your system, in which case you probably wouldn't have full access to that.

Comment: I'm not sure what a Print Spooler is but the pause button was ungrayed by changing the sharing options in the host desktop. The problem still persists though. All the other computers were also 'paused' and couldn't print. I need to pause only my own queue.